# Can nodejs be use on a static website for form submission?

Tags: html, node.js, express, nodemailer

I have this website that right now has a home page and a contact page. The page navigation is done through HTML and href links.

I have also made a server with node.js to handle the form submission on the contact page. It is using express, nodemailer, nodemailer-mailgun-transport for that.

I have been able to get the form submission to work running the node server.js command and going to localhost on my computer. It submits and sends it to my email just fine.

What I am running into, is how can I have that working when I just navigate to my contact page and not using the node command to run the server?

Anything will help.

Comment: depends on your host, can you host a nodeJs app? if Yes, then it's easy as you can simply use `express` to load the current static files, but have a server running where you can process the submissions ... first things first, tell us if you can run a Node application in your current host.

Comment: Well, right now all I have been doing is working on the localhost. hosting I was thinking of going with GoDaddy. I have been using express to dish up that webpage and I am able to get it to work that way. But I would like to run the HTML static and when click the for submission for it to call the backend and to run it that way.

Comment: Let me recommend you [Heroku](https://heroku.com), and if you're ok with Git, it's an amazing free hosting (will sleep the server if no activity in 30min, but quickly comes up) ...  and it's amazing for small projects. That way you can host your pages and have a node as a server in the same place

Answer (score 3):

Several ways you can go about that ...

> you have a static HTML page that you want to process form submissions in a NodeJs application

There are 2 smart ways to accomplish such idea

## 1. You host a NodeJs application

by making use of the `express.static()`, for example:

`server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const engine = require('./engine');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/api', async (req, res) => { 
    res.json(await engine.processForm(req.body));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => { 
    console.log(`ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

and your `engine.js`

```js
exports.processForm = formData => {
    // process form...
    return { message: 'Email sent', error: null };
};
```

in this particular example, you should have a directory called `public` with an `index.html` file that would contain your form and in that form, upon submission,  you could have something like:

```
<script>
  $( "#contactForm" ).submit(function( evt ) {
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.post( "/api", $(this).serialize(), function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data.response );
    });
  });
</script>
```

You will need to HOST the whole project in a hosting environment that can process NodeJs applications, like Heroku.

## 2. use Cloud functions, like Google Cloud or AWS Lambda

where you write your NodeJs application as a function, and you will have an HTTP Endpoint to run that function, and you simply add to your form

```html
<form action="https://your.endpoint.com/abcd123" ... >...</form>
```

either [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code) or [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/getting-started/) can help you with that

Comment: Thank you I will see what I can do! Thanks for the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

No. Node.js is server-side software: you can't embed it in static webpages.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "used on a static website" as running the code on the frontend, you can't. What you can do is, if you have a node.js server hosted elsewhere, you can send the form data to this server through a request.

If you want a node.js server only for handling form submissions, it might be a good idea to consider using Cloud Functions.

There is [this](https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e) tutorial on medium that might interest you.